# How to get the image blob from filepond for other components in vue

Tags: filepond

I am working on a page where there is a configuration setup and a preview pane. I wish for **filepond** to provide the bitmap(blob?) image when an image is uploaded so that it can be displayed in the live preview creator pane div tag rather than the **element(filepond)** it is originally shown on, is this possible.

I am using **vue-filepond**

Answer (score 1):

You receive the file item in the onprocessfile callback. The `file` property contains the file object. You can use `URL.createObjectURL` and pass the returned URL to an image src to show the image.

Assuming you have an `<img>` on the page something like this should work.

```js
const image = document.querySelector('img');
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileItem.file);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL